# Best Architecture - What's the best way to listen to an atom feed in java?

Tags: java, architecture, polling, atom-feed

I am reading Atom feed in Java , i do this at regular intervals of 30 seconds, Based on the feed i must show a different UI.

I am not happy polling for feeds every 30 seconds, and would like to know if a better architecture exists to tackle this problem.

I dont think that I can get push notifications from the Feed Source or can I?

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot. You can of course introduce a middle-layer component which will pull the feeds and then push them to your application but at the end of the day you would 'pull' anyway just to do the 'push'.

Comment: Thanks for your reply kris, So I am concluding that all Feed readers poll the subscribed websites at regular intervals , and if we want to listen to atom / rss feeds using Java then there's no other way than polling at regular intervals .

Comment: @user1673160 Not all feed readers are based just on polling. Some feeds do support push notifications, based on the pubsubhubbub specification: https://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/, and some feed readers do exploit this capability.

Comment: Its an extension to Atom and Rss but thanks a lot for sharing, didn't know that smth like that exists.

Comment: @Kris Yeah, that's currently true, but the PSHB specification in its next version will not be tied to ATOM/RSS feeds -- it will be a generic pub-sub mechanism for the Web. You can follow the development here: https://github.com/pubsubhubbub/PubSubHubbub and here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/pubsubhubbub